# rownum not working for update in PL/SQL containing update query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a total of 193267 records to be updated and it needs to be done in a batch of 10,000 records, however the update is not taking up rownum value

It is not taking 10,000 number in batch.

```sql
set serveroutput ON
DECLARE
    ROWNUM NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        UPDATE billing.account_country
        SET    contract_type_id = NULL
        WHERE  ROWNUM <= 10000
               AND mdate < SYSDATE - 300
               AND mdate >= SYSDATE - 500
               AND id IS NOT NULL
               AND id IN ( 209 )
               AND contract_type_id < 1000;

        ROWNUM := SQL%rowcount;

        dbms_output.Put_line('row num:'
                             ||ROWNUM);

        IF ( ROWNUM = 0 ) THEN
          EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.Put_line('done..');
END;
```

result is as below:

```
row num:193267
row num:0
done..
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what `ROWNUM` is. It does not indicate the record count in the table. For each row returned by a query, the [`ROWNUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255)  just returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table. 193267 rows are actually too less to require anything other than a simple, **single update** statement.

Comment: @KaushikNayak is there any function available that i can use to update only 10000 rows at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem in your code - Works for me:

```
DECLARE
    i           NUMBER;

    sqlCreate   VARCHAR2 (4000)
                    := 'CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (mycolumn VARCHAR2(100))';

    sqlDrop     VARCHAR2 (4000) := 'DROP TABLE MYTABLE';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCreate;

    FOR x IN 1 .. 10
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into MYTABLE values(' || x || ')';
    END LOOP;

    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE MYTABLE r
           SET r.mycolumn = r.mycolumn || ''x''
         WHERE ROWNUM <= 4
           AND not r.mycolumn like ''%x%''';

        i := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('i: ' || i);

        IF (i = 0)
        THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlDrop;
END;
```

Output:

```
i: 4
i: 4
i: 2
i: 0
```

Perhaps

```
`AND contract_type_id < 1000;`
```

..is not enough. Shouldn't there be a

```
AND NOT contract_type_id is null;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is that your commits do not exceed 10,000 records per commit (but commits are still permitted to be smaller than 10,000 records per commit), then you are in luck.

You don't need manage your own commit size or consider enqueue at all.
Oracle has built-in utilities for this sort of thing.

I'll add an example of handling the 10K chunk yourself far below, but just using Oracle's builtins will save time and avoid bugs.

Here's an example that uses **`DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE`** (you can set the **parallel degree** to 1 if you don't actually want to parallelize much).

The notable pieces here are the `CHUNK_SIZE => 10000` to limit the commit size, the `PARALLEL_LEVEL => 1` to limit parallel, and the `ROWID BETWEEN :STARD_ID AND :END_ID` (also the `ROWNUM` has been removed, but the rest of your original query has been left as-is, including the `ID IS NOT NULL` and `ID IN` elements)

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_TASK(TASK_NAME => 'NULL_CONTRACT_TYPE');

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID(
    TASK_NAME => 'NULL_CONTRACT_TYPE' ,
    TABLE_OWNER => 'BILLING',
    TABLE_NAME => 'ACCOUNT_COUNTRY', 
    BY_ROW => TRUE, 
    CHUNK_SIZE => 10000);

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK(
    TASK_NAME => 'NULL_CONTRACT_TYPE' ,
    SQL_STMT => 'UPDATE account_country SET contract_type_id = NULL ' ||
                'WHERE  mdate < SYSDATE - 300 ' ||
                'AND mdate >= SYSDATE - 500 ' ||
                'AND id IS NOT NULL AND id IN ( 209 ) ' ||
                'AND contract_type_id < 1000 ' ||
                'AND ROWID BETWEEN :START_ID AND :END_ID',
    LANGUAGE_FLAG => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE, 
    PARALLEL_LEVEL => 1);

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK(TASK_NAME => 'NULL_CONTRACT_TYPE');

END;
/
```

Oracle will then do the rest for you -- committing in the chunks you specify, updating only the target records, etc.

But, if you still want to do it yourself, one approach is to fetch from a cursor and limit the number of target rows.  Below is an example of that as well (as before, I've left your original query intact).  From your original query, it would appear that ID is not unique, so I'm using `ROWID`s for this example.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE ROWID_LIST IS TABLE OF ROWID;
  V_UPDATE_TARGETS ROWID_LIST := ROWID_LIST();
  CURSOR UPDATE_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY_TARGETS IS (
    SELECT ROWID FROM ACCOUNT_COUNTRY
    WHERE  mdate < SYSDATE - 300
       AND mdate >= SYSDATE - 500
       AND id IS NOT NULL AND id IN ( 209 )
       AND contract_type_id < 1000);
BEGIN
OPEN UPDATE_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY_TARGETS;
LOOP
  EXIT WHEN UPDATE_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY_TARGETS%NOTFOUND;
  FETCH UPDATE_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY_TARGETS BULK COLLECT INTO V_UPDATE_TARGETS LIMIT 10000;
  FORALL ROWID_INDEX IN 1..V_UPDATE_TARGETS.COUNT
    UPDATE ACCOUNT_COUNTRY
    SET CONTRACT_TYPE_ID = NULL
    WHERE ROWID = V_UPDATE_TARGETS(ROWID_INDEX);
  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
CLOSE UPDATE_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY_TARGETS;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem with your code is that you have created a variable named ROWNUM and assigned a value of 0 initially. So when you query runs for the first time, it will always pass the condition of

`WHERE  ROWNUM <= 10000`

and your query will update all the eligible records based on other conditions.
Hence, in the current scenario, since you have records more than 10k, your query will run only once. **If you had less than 10k records**, then your program would have got into **INFINITE loop**.

The only change you need to do is remove the below declaration of **ROWNUM** from your code, and your code will work as expected.

`ROWNUM NUMBER := 0;`

Then the program will use **Oracle's builtin ROWNUM** clause.